# I am trying manually update all static HTML files

Tags: javascript, php, html, static, shared-hosting

I have right now one project on static **HTML** with two languages and I have to manage everything by myself. 
So if something new appears in header/footer I have to update 20 HTML files.

Also this project is hosted on normal shared hosting. 
How can I make less painful, if I have to change something? 
Right now i just bulk find/change in folder with sublime.

> P.S I can't use any CMS. Must be static.

Comment: You could use a php include

Comment: Could you please provide more information and examples?

Comment: `P.S I can't use any CMS. Must be static.` What's your reasoning?

Comment: Very broad and no code examples. Start building and post issues which you get stuck.

Comment: Obviously the server doesn't support PHP since it has to be static (or is it a mistake?) - Anyway, I provided a JS answer that could fit with a static-only hosting.

Comment: Chances the server doesnt support any dynamic language is pretty slim. If true moving host would be my choice. Failing that, i would still build it with basic php includes locally, then just build a shell script that saves the generated html and ftps it.

Comment: @Derek. I have provided with a solution for both methods for the `STATIC` websites as well as for the `DYNAMIC` websites. Please go thoughts that and share thoughts regarding that. It is better to use `Jquery` for STATIC websites to load the data and `PHP` for loading up the `DYNAMIC`. Hope so it helps for you to understand well about both the scripting languages.

Comment: @Steve : It is true, but some corporate restrictions can explain why and what (like old-fashioned intranet) and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `HTML` content of the header in a `PHP` file and include it in every page, like this:

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
```

This way you only have one file (`header.php`) to edit.

More details on `include()` can be found at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 2):

Since it has to be static, you probably can't use PHP.

An alternative that works on **modern browser** would be to use Javascript to include the header and footer from another file.

You have several options, one is [using jQuery load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/). Example to include two files contained in the `resources` folder :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Demo load for header and footer</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header"><!-- HEADER COMES HERE --></div>

    <!-- Main content comes here -->

    <div id="footer"><!-- FOOTER COMES HERE --></div>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#header" ).load( "/resources/header.html" );
        $( "#footer" ).load( "/resources/footer.html" );
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Please, consider a **fallback** by filling the #header and #footer divs with a content that would be displayed if javascript is not enabled. Also consider a fallback if load() doesn't work (look at the doc for this, there is an example).

Answer (score 1):

**Suggestion One:**

> P.S I can't use any CMS. Must be static.

You can use the **Jquery** to load up the files that you have in the respective place based on the needs that you have.

```
.load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )
```

**Description:** Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.

Note: The event handling suite also has a method named .load(). jQuery determines which method to fire based on the set of arguments passed to it.

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#some-menu').load('some-local-path/menu.html');
});
```

Provided you can have the ID of the DIV as you given and then it will load up the data over to that place and you can change it dynamically.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="some_menu">
<!-- Loads the Menu Part Over Here -->
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#some-menu').load('some-local-path/menu.html');
        // Like wise you can load up all the data that you need over here and place the necessary div over to the HTML.
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

> If it is **not a static** you can follow up with the below one as i have mentioned using the PHP.

**Alternative Reference:**

It is better to use PHP since it supports awesome features and you can create your own CMS using the PHP.

### More Clear Explanations

- Look for the items that are being static on to your site and it has to be shown in all the pages.
- Copy them and place in the respective files namely header in the header.php and footer in footer.php and so on and then you need to do one more thing alone.
- You need to include all the files that are being given by you and thats the trick.

Entire Page will look like.

```
<html>
<head>Title of the Page</head>
<?php include 'scripts.php'; ?>
<body>
<?php include 'header_menu.php'; ?>
// Page content
<?php include 'sidebar.php'; ?>
//Page Contents    
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

> Like this way you can do it for your header,footer and whatever files you need to do so and if you update the single file alone it will be replicating in all the files even tones of files you have.

**Basic include example**

The `include()` statement includes and evaluates the specified file.

The include command simply takes all the text that exists in the specified file and copies it into the file that uses the include command. Include is quite useful when you want to include the same PHP, HTML, or text segment on multiple pages of a website. The include command is used widely by PHP web developers. Like PHP Echo, include is not a function, but a language construct.

**vars.php**

```
<?php
$color = 'green';
$fruit = 'apple';
?>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
echo "A $color $fruit"; // A
include 'vars.php';
echo "A $color $fruit"; // A green apple
?>
```

Comment: Part of this are copied from https://www.coursehero.com/file/p2utc6n/Include-Recap-The-include-command-simply-takes-all-the-text-that-exists-in-the/ and other sources. It would have been nice to quote sources

Comment: I have never ever copied from here. Please don't bluff over here. I have referred only from the PHP manual.

Comment: I need explanation for my downvote. Please Justify

Comment: True, some sentences are found on several website and it probably comes from the PHP manual. Sorry for this, no arm intended of course :-)

Comment: How come you are saying that i have copied from there on @brclz. I have never done that.

Comment: Please be specific on to what you are mentioning. Since this might cause bad impression over others who refer to my code.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I understood if you want to manage many HTML files in a static web I think you need a HTML template.

I would recommend to use "http://handlebarsjs.com/" you can use it as well in static pages.

I hope it helps.